# Using SOFLAM and Javelin by yourself

Tags: battlefield-3

There's not a lot of organized teamwork on Battlefield 3, so it's hard to have a SOFLAM user assisting the Javelin launcher. Is it possible to spawn as the recon class, set your SOFLAM down, commit suicide, then spawn as an engineer with the Javelin equipped?

Comment: I would think so... things like mortars, spawn points etc stay even after you die... I've even gotten a Spawn Point to stay, after I've spawned on it. I picked up a enemies scout pack placed it and eventually died... but when I resawned with my original class it was still there and I could keep on spawning on it

Answer (score 3):

Anti-Tank mines, EOD bots, Mortars, T-UGS, SOFLAM, MAV's, Claymores and Radio Beacons (provided you don't spawn on them) will not disappear upon death.

Only C4 disappears upon death.

Comment: But does this take into account the fact that he will be switching classes?  Does that effect the lifespan of the objects?

Comment: note that there were some changes to spawning as recon. Your squad *cannot* spawn on you (as recon) once you drop the mobile spawn point, they can only spawn on the mobile spawn point.

Comment: Actually, you still can detonate your C4 after respawn, and I don't know, how it is with EOD or mortar, but T-UGS and MAV _do_ disappear upon death.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually impossible. I've tried it earlier today, if you place a SOFLAM and commit suicide, re spawn as an engineer with a Javelin, the SOFLAM **will** be gone.

The only way to use SOFLAM and still take something down yourself is to use a Guided Shell for a tank or a helicopter. Even that is difficult, having to get out to laser tag (SOFLAM is meant to be autonomous but it's bugged to hell, doesn't tag things right in front of it sometimes) something then get back in, get a lock on and fire.

To sum up, no, you can't put a SOFLAM, suicide, and use a Javelin. It needs two people.

Answer (score 3):

If you start of as a recon with soflam, then commit suicide, then re-spawn as an engineer with javelin and go to the same spot where your recon kit was left last you can do it. Just switch to recon and set up the soflam, then switch back to engineer.

Comment: Excellent work around. That everyone seems to have missed! I assume picking up your engineer gear doesnt destroy it. Plus when you spawn again as engineer, will it be destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

I see most of these comments were from earlier this month and I found some comments to be inconsistent with my own experience. Maybe a new patch changed things?

Anyways, my AT mines stay (longer than 20 seconds. I think they stay forever) because I would continue to get points after I die (and more than 20 seconds since). Same as my C4. I'd place my C4s and get killed, but then I'd respawn and detonate and still get kills. But I'm here for the same question. It would appear my SOFLAM disappears every time after I respawn as engineer, which is troubling.

Comment: yeah I have noticed the mobile recon bot tends to destroy itself a short time after I die and respawn as recon, too.